# Best sound software to make sound by keyboard like piano [linux]?

Tags: sound-effects, keyboard, piano

What is the best software to make sound by keyboard?

Piano-keyboard interruption interceptor like keylogger to play music just by keyboard.

Pretty to see some effects, processors plugins, feature like background job, e.g. I'm enable software, configure effects, and simply start programming, sounds of organ(letters) cross with guitar solo(numbers), under drums(spec buttons < ^ >) fill my room.

I'm mean that keyboard piano must be powerful as Adobe Photoshop.

Open Source!

Comment: Can you reword this question to avoid asking for a product recommendation, and instead ask for what functionality would be essential/important based on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://jack-keyboard.sourceforge.net/
Vkeybd (http://alsa.opensrc.org/Vkeybd)
http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/

Have not used any of them, this is just what a Google search brings up.

You might want to clarify this part of your question:

> Pretty to see some effects, processors plugins, feature like background job, e.g. I'm enable software, configure effects, and simply start programming, sounds of organ(letters) cross with guitar solo(numbers), under drums(spec buttons < ^ >) fill my room.

Comment: I'm looking for piano-keyboard software rich by effects like Adobe Photoshop.(metaphor)

Comment: You have forgotten to mention [ZynAddSubFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZynAddSubFX) which is included in package managers (Fedora, Ubuntu). Instructions on how to install vkeybd can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1003466).

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is Kontakt / Kontakt player by Native Instruments! You can download soundbanks and play them with your keyboard.

If this does not give you enough features, I recommend you try out a basic DAW like Fl Studio. This has alot of features (just like Adobe Photoshop has for picture editing).

Sources: I'm a music producer.

~ Much Love, Macto Dfacto
http://www.mactodfacto.com

Comment: I'm talking about free and open-source. Free to make any changes in code. Plus, see, its looks like fake: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.mactodfacto.com . There are only 5 pages on this site. Did you buy this soft yourself?